# How to convert content div with canvas to PDF using canvas2pdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, html5-canvas

I try read more at https://github.com/joshua-gould/canvas2pdf. In here, have a guide to create new a PDF canvas, but I would like to use that have a div contains two canvas

```js
$('#PDF').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // In here, I need get data a div with two canvas , 
  // and then add this to below
  //Create a new PDF canvas context.
  var ctx = new canvas2pdf.Context(blobStream());

  //draw your canvas like you would normally
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
  // more canvas drawing, etc...

  //convert your PDF to a Blob and save to file
  ctx.stream.on('finish', function() {
    var blob = ctx.stream.toBlob('application/pdf');
    saveAs(blob, 'example.pdf', true);
  });
  ctx.end();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pdf-viewer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%; background: #d4d4d4; overflow: scroll">
  <canvas height="792" width="612" style="margin: 2px auto; display: block; border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);"></canvas>
  <canvas height="792" width="612" style="margin: 2px auto; display: block; border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);"></canvas>
</div>
```

I need a way get data in div and using this convert to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to run the library itself but already found this code which I think is what you are looking for:

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var text = document.querySelector('.page');

//Create a new PDF canvas context.
var stream = blobStream();
var ctx = new canvas2pdf.PdfContext(stream);
eval(text);
console.log(stream);
ctx.stream.on('finish', function() {
  iframe.src = ctx.stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="page-2" class="page">
    <h1>Second Page</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <img src="assets/images/logo-georg.png" width="300">
  </div>
  <iframe style="border:1px solid black;" width="600" height="775"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```